# R programming commands on graphics

Tags: r, legend

Please tell the command for writing following as the legend at top left of a graph :

`(\mu_1,\mu_2)=(8,7)` where 8 and 7 come from the value of the variables mu1 and mu2, assigned in the program.

Comment: Have a look at `?legend`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bquote`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bquote.html) to write the expression and place your variables `mu1` and `mu2` within `.()`:

```
mu1 <- 7
mu2 <- 8
plot(1,1)
legend("topleft", legend=bquote((mu[1]*","*mu[2])==(.(mu1)*","*.(mu2))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `substitute` function is very good for this scenario (borrowing @Julian's example)

```
mu1 <- 7
mu2 <- 8
plot(1,1)
legend("topleft", 
    legend=substitute((list(mu[1], mu[2]))==(list(mu1,mu2)), 
    list(mu1=mu1, mu2=mu2))
)
```